# Two answers in one--how do I support one of them?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535841) is two different answers. I support one and not the other. What do I do?

Comment: The net outcome of voting up one of the answers and down the other would be `0`. so... don't vote?

Comment: I think your comment pointing out the problem is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly why the site allows the same user to leave multiple answers so you don't have to deal with it.  But some users don't do this - they still leave combined answers with multiple solutions.

But the fact that they make it confusing is their problem, not yours, so you should handle this just like anything else on the site - you vote based on your overall perception of the answer as a whole.

If you think that the "correct half" of the answer makes the overall answer useful, then you should upvote.  If you think that the "wrong half" of the answer makes the overall answer not useful, then you should downvote.  If you think each half of the answer cancel each other out, then you do nothing (essentially your upvote and downvote cancel each other out).

And of course, you are encouraged to comment when you think a post could be improved, so you could also leave a comment explaining what is wrong with the post and how it could be fixed.  It might be as simple as suggesting that the solutions are different enough that the answers could be split into separate answers.

Comment: Okay, I've requested the answerer split it. Thanks.

Answer (score -12):

I could **repost one of the answers** as community wiki.

Comment: Don't do this.  This is just duplicating information in another answer for very limited benefit.